Why do some languages have two words for "two"/"second"?
French: deuxième vs. second (= second)
Vietnamese: (thứ) hai vs. (thứ) nhì (= second, nhì is non-Sino-Vietnamese reading of Chinese 二)
Chinese: 二 vs. 两 (= two)
In each language, both words have their own standard uses; that is, one can't replace the other in every context, and they are not dialectal.
Why the need to have two words?

Ordinal vs cardinal, and many languages have borrowed numbers from other languages, while keeping their older numbers.

@curiousdannii French deuxième and second are both ordinals and both language-internal creations.

@curiousdannii the French examples are both native and both ordinal. The Chinese example also has both being cardinal (although 二 can also be ordinal) and, if not native, an old borrowing that's been thoroughly nativised. Vietnamese seems to be the only one that fits your explanation

(and even within Vietnamese, there is also nhị which is cardinal "two" but borrowed, versus native cardinal hai and borrowed ordinal nhì)

The French numbers are derived from Latin where they were a ordinal/cardinal pair. I don't know how they then evolved into their present French uses.

@Tristan I specifically mentioned hai as an ordinal in its own right

but yes agree in general it makes sense for nhì to be borrowed and replace hai in some contexts

@curiousdannii deuxième developed post-Latin, and is transparently an ordinal formation. It derives from the cardinal sure, but in no-sense did deuxième and second ever form an ordinal/cardinal pair

Goidelic (Irish and Scots Gaelic) might be another good example. Using Irish for examples here, there’s a dó (cardinal used when counting), dhá (cardinal used with noun), beirt (cardinal used for people), dar(n)a (general ordinal), dóú (ordinal with stronger connection specifically to the number two, and also used for 12, 22, 32, 42, etc.). The distinction between numerals for counting and numerals enumeration is also found for 1 and 4, and the forms for counting people are found from 1 to 12. And Latin of course has no less than six systems of numerals.

@Lambie as noted, only the Vietnamese example is "two" vs "second", and it also has two words for cardinal "two". The French example has two words for ordinal "second" and the Chinese example has two words for cardinal "two"

@Lambie "deuxième" and "second" are patently not "two" and "second". The title refers to the question pointing out some languages have two words for "second", and others have two words for "two".

I guess I didn't understand the question.

The way Chinese differentiated is because of the emergence of classifiers in the Late Han to Tang, co-opting the use of "pair". In most Min Chinese, you see 一 and 蜀 ('one' as a cardinal and 'one' as a pre-classifier count) forming a similar pair; there is some debate whether the two are actually related.

Relevant chapter and map in World Atlas of Liguistic Structures (WALS)

It's not unusual for small numbers to have irregular ordinals, i.e. ordinals not derived from the cardinals. In Indo-European languages, the first ordinal not infrequently uses an expression meaning 'foremost' (e.g. English first, Latin prīmus, Greek πρῶτος, Sanskrit प्रथम prathama), and the second one one meaning 'the other' (e.g. Norwegian annan, Lithuanian añtras, Latin alter) or 'the following' (Latin secundus).
French, as a descendent from Latin, initially inherited secundus, but a series of sound changes rendered it increasingly unrecognisable: in Old French it must have become *seon (not attested), and today it's son (only preserved in the meaning 'bran', apparently because bran is obtained from a second sifting of flour). The verb it was originally derived from, sequor, underwent its own changes and ended up as sivre in Old French (today suivre).
So by Old French the second ordinal was both irregular within the system and etymologically completely opaque to speakers, and a need was felt to resolve this. Two approaches were taken.
First, the literate segment of the population very early on reborrowed secundus from Latin, which continued to exist as a literary language; as early as 1119, we have an attestation of secunt, and this became modern French second. (It remained exempt from many later sound changes because the Latin served as a continuous corrective model.)
As a learned borrowing this obviously didn't immediately catch on as the general-purpose ordinal for the whole of society, so to resolve the problem they still had the unwashed masses did what people often do in this situation, and used analogy to create greater regularity in the system: a new ordinal was coined on the model of the cardinal, just as most other ordinals were based on the cardinals. This was deuxième (actually Old French deusime, attested in the early 14th century), from deux (Old French deus).
This is why French has both deuxième and second (and son, if you like). I don't know enough about Vietnamese or Chinese to explain the situation there, though it is true that numbers are often borrowed from neighbouring languages because of their use in trade; this most often applies to numbers higher than 3, but I know e.g. Japanese borrowed the smaller numbers from Middle Chinese as well.

Japanese is the other way around: it’s borrowed all numbers from Chinese, retaining only (additional) indigenous words for the smaller ones.

Any evidence that deuxieme was pushed top down?  Seems unlikely.

@AdamBittlingmayer That's the opposite of what I said?

@Cairnarvon Maybe I misinterpreted.  What do "they" and "had" mean in "they still had the unwashed masses did (sic)..."?

@AdamBittlingmayer "to resolve the problem they still had" is one clause.
